# unable to create virtual host in xampp installed in ubuntu14.04

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ubuntu-14.04

my httpd.conf file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       raghib-Inspiron-7420
127.0.0.1       project0.local
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

i wanna create a project0.local

my httpd-vhost.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias www.localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /home/raghib/vhosts/%0/html
  ServerName project0.local
  ServerAlias www.%0
  ErrorLog logs/%0.local-error_log
  CustomLog logs/%0.local-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have uncommented Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in my htttpd.conf file

```
I HAVE CREATED index.html in my /home/raghib/vhosts/project0/html/index.html when i write http://localhost/ and http://project0.local both refer to      /opt/lampp/htdocs

I WANT MY http://project0 to redirect into/home/raghib/vhosts/project0/html/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this website:

[Click Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)